# 413 Payload Too Large error nginx / ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, server

My upload file size is 230 MB and

nginx configuration nginx.conf

```
  client_max_body_size 3000M
```

my php ini file configuration

```
     post_max_size 3000M

    upload_max_filesize 3000M
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure both nginx and nodejs/python/php (backend service) to allow upload size.

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Add the following line to http or server or location context to increase the size limit in nginx.conf, enter:

```
# set client body size to 300M #
client_max_body_size 300M;
```

The client_max_body_size directive assigns the maximum accepted body size of client request, indicated by the line Content-Length in the header of request. If size is greater the given one, then the client gets the error “Request Entity Too Large” (413).

Reload the nginx webserver, enter:

```
/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -s reload
```

Use nginx itself to reload it:

```
/sbin/nginx -s reload
```

For RHEL/CentOS/Debian/Ubuntu Linux, try:

```
service nginx reload
```

If you are using systemd based system run:

```
sudo systemctl reload nginx.service
```

If you are using NodeJS:

```
app.use(express.limit('300M'));
```

Your php installation also put limits on upload file size. Edit php.ini and set the following directives

```
;This sets the maximum amount of memory in bytes that a script is allowed to allocate
memory_limit = 300M

;The maximum size of an uploaded file.
upload_max_filesize = 300M

;Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file upload. To upload large files, this value must be larger than upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 300M
```

Save and close the file. Make sure you reload/restart back-end nginx web server as per your setup.

Comment: thank you. only solution that finally worked for me!